# Can I use "I just got 22 years old"?

Tags: grammaticality

In my mother language, I can say "I got 18 years old today".

I want to use the same concept in English, but I googled the sentence structure, and did not get a lot of hits.

So I was wondering, is it okay to use it this way, or is there a real correct way for it?

Comment: Try "turned" instead of "got," and see what happens. :^)

Comment: I don't really understand the exact reason for *got* being wrong here, since you can say *"I just got a year older"*. But native speakers certainly wouldn't use it.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I think all such usage of *"got"* is relatively new and idiomatic, so things are probably somewhat "fluid". Today, I think most speakers are fine with *"My wife got fat"*, and *"I got annoyed"*, though for me at least they're slightly casual/informal usages. And I couldn't possibly endorse *"I got disappointed"*, but quite possibly even that would be considered okay by many people a few decades from now. Me - I still wince at the standard American *"What time you got?"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: In the U.S., *"What time you got?"* is considered ungrammatical, but is a common way to say *"What time have you got?"*, which I would claim is grammatical. I'd consider it a different usage than *"I got annoyed"* or *"I got disappointed"*.

Comment: @Peter Shor: Yeah, but Americans also say ["What time do you got?"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22what+time+do+you+got%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). It's the use of *"got"* that grates for me as a Brit, since our standard form is *"What time do you **have**?"*. All I meant was Americans are farther down the track when it comes to these new(-ish) constructions using *got/get*.

Comment: Shouldn't it be I just got "a 22 year old" or "an 18 year old" today

Comment: @FumbleFingers: RE: "Americans also say 'What time (do) you got?'" ~ I won't pretend I've never heard that, but I will say I don't hear it very often. Usually, I hear "What time do you have?" or, much more frequently, "What time is it?" or "Do you have the time?"

Comment: It seems as though the fundamental key to this are the subtle differences between uses of the word _got_ in constructs variously meaning _acquire_, _become_ and _possess_, further complicated by some notable differences in usage between BrE and AmE.

Comment: 'I am...'. Surely, or 'it's my birthday today!'.

Comment: @Brian Nixon: I suspect Americans on average use *"do"* and *"get"* more in these somewhat vague constructions, but neither side of the pond speaks of *"Getting 18"*. The nearest we have is *"Get **to be** 18"*, which I only find acceptable in certain contexts (*"I only got to be 18 today, so tonight will be the first time I'll be legally watching an X-rated movie"*).

Comment: In “I just got 22 years old” it sounds like “22 years old” is a disease.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I got 18 years old today"

//warning: not a native speaker.

"I've turned 22 years old today"(probably more correct) or "I've become 22-years old today".

"Just got 22 years old" sounds like you're talking about somebody else - to me it sounds like "the only person present at this location is 22 years old".

Comment: A native speaker would probably say simply: *I turned 22 today.*

Comment: "Just got 22 years old" is unidiomatic even when speaking about someone else.

Comment: @Shoe: Shouldn't be "I've turned" suitable for situation when person has just celebrate his/her birthday?

Comment: @MarkBeadles: To me it sounds like this sentence is suitable for situation when you're describing (to somebody else) that aside from you there's only one 22 years old person in the room, although I might be wrong about that. Interestingly if you search for phrase "just got 20 years old", there will be some hits, but it looks like this sentence is used mostly by non-native speakers.

Comment: Yes, my intuition as a native speaker of US English is that it's not quite right.

Comment: @SigTerm, Both the past simple and present perfect are possible here. It depends on how the speaker conceptualises the word *today*. For me *today* refers to the moment in the day when I became 22 (at midnight - the turn of the day); hence the past tense. But others might use the present perfect to emphasise the present relevance of the *turning*.

Answer (score 5):

*I got 18 years old today - wrong
*I've become 22-years old today - wrong

*I turn 22 years old today - correct
*I am 22 years old today - correct

From a native speaker in the UK :)

Comment: I'm not so sure I'd label _become_ as "wrong." Maybe a little "awkward", maybe "unusual" in that context, but not "wrong". _What will happen to the children, after they become 18?_ [It can work](http://books.google.com/books?id=dP_TElE4GEoC&pg=PA85&dq=%22become+21%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=W2bcT9SDJMiq2QWI5M3HDQ&ved=0CEYQ6AEwAjgU#v=onepage&q=%22become%2021%22&f=false).

Comment: Also "I have turned 22 years old today" or "Today I became 22", "Today is my 22nd birthday", "I reached 22 today" etc.etc.etc...

Comment: @J.R. TLM is saying the sentence given  "I've become 22-years old today" is wrong. Some other use of 'become' might be right.

Comment: @Mitch - Yes, that's what I meant – I wouldn't label _"I've become 22 years old today"_ as wrong. While it may not sound all that natural, and it's not how I would announce it, I can't find any reason to deem it incorrect.

Comment: @J.R. OK. Well then count me a vote for the opposite direction. It sounds wrong to me.

Comment: @Mitch - It _sounds_ wrong to me, too. But I'm having trouble accepting the fact that it _is_ wrong. It's certainly not idiomatic – I think we both agree quite strongly on that.

Answer (score 2):

I would say *I turned 22 today.*

Answer (score -1):

I have reached 22, often accompanied by a qualifier, such as: the ripe old age of.... would be acceptable, and more in the spirit of 'I got'. It would not be very good English, but you could say: I have got to 22 so far, giving the impression that it has been a struggle or that it is one step along a road. It is frustrating how use of idiom can make it difficult to express complex ideas simply in foreign languages.

Comment: Welcome to SE! There is already an accepted answer to this question. How does your answer improve what has already been posted?

Answer (score -1):

It‘s a very easy question. Spanish uses „to have“ when it comes describing age. Englisch (and probably most Germanic languages) use the verb „to be“. So, one is a particular age. One doesn’t have a particular age. „I am 22 today“ or „I am 22“ are possibilities.  When it‘s your birthday, English uses the verb „to turn“, like everyone else mentioned. So it‘s „I turned 22 today.“ There‘s no explanation for it. You could say „I became 22 today“ but that would sound a bit formal, and a little odd. Stick with „turn“ and you will be saying what 99% of native speakers would say.

Comment: Hi Jan, welcome to EL&U. Note that our site is a bit different from the others: it's not a forum for posting opinions. Instead, we're looking for *correct, authoritative answers, preferably supported by evidence*. I don't see what value your post adds to the existing answers, and the non-English orthography is off-putting. For guidance, see [answer] and take the [Tour].

Comment: Well, was my answer incorrect? You said you are looking for „authoritative“ answers, but English has no official language authority, like the German Duden, so who is the authority? And if there is no authority, then isn’t everything everyone’s opinion? You also asked for supporting evidence. What kind of evidence? Sorry if the quotation marks seem offputting, „ ...“but I use a German language keyboard and that‘s how quotation marks are done in German. I can‘t change that.

Comment: For word meanings and usage, OED is seen as definitive but any of the major online dictionaries (Oxford, M-W, Collins, Macmillan, Cambridge) are regarded as authoritative, and [other online dictionaries](https://www.onelook.com/?w=got&ls=a), Wikipedia, Google Ngrams, major style guides, reputable grammar websites, etynomline etc are also commonly used for supporting evidence. The point being, they help differentiate an answer from *mere personal opinion*. Some find this too formal and burdensome, in which case Quora or Reddit might be a better fit.